# Coin Tossing - Simple Program

Tags: c

We were tasked to make a program about Coin tossing. I would like someone to recheck my code whether there is a need to be changed or clarified.

This is the question:

> Write a program that simulates coin tossing. For each toss of the coin the program should print Heads or Tails. Let the program toss the coin 100 times, and count the number of times each side of coin appears. Print the results. The program should call a separate function flip that takes no arguments and returns 0 for tails and 1 for heads. [Note: If the program realistically simulates the coin tossing, then each side of the coin should appear approximately half the time for a total of approximately 50 heads and 50 tails.]

Note: Function Calls should be applied to the program.

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int flip();

int main ()
{
    int coin, counter, tails = 0, heads = 0;
    
printf("\nA program that simulates Coin Tossing with a probability of getting half of Heads or Tails\n\n");

for (counter = 1; counter <= 100; counter++)
    {
        coin =  flip (); //Function Call
 
        if(coin == 0)
        {
            printf("T ");
            tails = tails + 1;
        }
        else if( coin == 1) 
        {
            printf("H ");
            heads = heads + 1;
        }
    }
 
 //Total Count of Heads and Tails
    printf("\n\n--- TOTAL COUNT ---\n", heads);
    printf("Heads was tossed %d times\n", heads);
    printf("Tails was tossed %d times\n", tails);
 
}

//Approximately 50 Heads and 50 Tails
int flip()
{
    return rand( ) % 2;
    getch();
    
}
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please don't "fix" the code after answers have been posted; you'll render those answers nonsensical. I'll roll back your changes to the original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One oversight (remove the heads):
`printf("\n\n--- TOTAL COUNT ---\n", heads);`

you may also want to remove `getch();` inside `flip()` and fix the indentation of the overall file if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

1. NO need to define function signature above the main and implement later. You can do this in one way.
2. Need to return 0 in your main function(last line in your main function).
3. Don't use unnecessary header unless you use their function/value.